# Hardhat-ethers version issues

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

when I run some basic ethers methods such as ... it does not work on latest version of hardhat. but i run the same script on old version of hardhat, and it works.  what gives?

**Doesn't work:**
{

"dependencies": {
"hardhat": "^2.19.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^4.0.0"
}
}

**works:**

"dependencies": {
"hardhat": "^2.12.6"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^2.0.1"
}
}